# Editing a tablerow with MVC and AngularJS and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a function that enables you to edit registered users. I'm trying to edit FirstName, LastName and Email. 
In this method I get the stuff that is written into the input fields, but Id is null so naturally editedUser is always null aswell. How can I get the users Id into the method so editedUser get's set to the user being edited?

```
[HttpPost]
        public User EditUser([FromBody]EditUserModel model)
        {
            var editedUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == model.Id);

            editedUser.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            editedUser.LastName = model.LastName;
            editedUser.Email = model.Email;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return editedUser;
```

What my js function looks like:

service:

```
editUser: function (user) {
                return $http.post('/api/userspa', user)
```

controller:

```
 $scope.editUser = function () {
                var user = $scope.selectedUser;
                UserService.editUser(user).success(function (data) {
                    console.log('Updated', data)
                })
```

From the developer console: "
You clicked on: `Object {UserID: 58, FirstName: "test1", LastName: "testsson", Email: "testEdit@test.se", RegistrationDate: "2015-01-14T15:48:04.777"}`"

EDIT: added js controller.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'UserService', function ($scope, $http, UserService) {

        UserService.getUsers()
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.users = data;
            })
            .error(function () {
                $scope.error = "Couldnt load data or there was none.";
            }
            )

        $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
            UserService.getUser(user.UserID).success(function (data) {
                console.log("user ", data);
                $scope.selectedUser = user;
            })
        }

        $scope.editUser = function () {
            var user = $scope.selectedUser;
            UserService.editUser(user).success(function (data) {
                console.log('Updated', data)
            }).
            error(function () {
                $scope.error = console.log('Something went wrong')
            });
        }
```

Comment: So how do you feel that `user` object in JS ? can you post your JS Code?

Comment: Why aren't you including the ID as well so it won't be null ?

Comment: I have included the ID in the EditUserModel class but it appears on the properties that are availble to edit get's passed into the EditUser method. Or where do you mean I should include it?

Comment: If it's in the `EditUserModel` then how come you say it's always null ? Or maybe I misunderstood ?

Comment: public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; } that's whats in my EditUserModel but, i get everything in there except the Id, im thinking it's because how I display it(?) with ng-model="selectedUser.NameAndEmailProperties" and thats whats get sent to the API? But how would i do it any differently?

Comment: If it's null in the controller, it means that it's getting sent as null from the client side. You need to make sure you send it just like you send all the other data. Perhaps a hidden field containing the ID.

Comment: I tried adding <input type="hidden" ng-model="selectedUser.UserID" id="UserID" name="UserID"/> to the div where im posting the data, but model.Id is still null.
  This is the object that gets posted to the API: http://snag.gy/fxE7V.jpg

Comment: Looks good. The only issue is that you are sending `UserID`, so you need to change your `EditUserModel` property from `Id` to `UserID`  so the binding will work.

Comment: @howDisWorks No problem! I'll gather up what we talked about in an answer to wrap this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what we talked about in the comments, the fix was to send the `ID` from the client as well, that way you'll have it in the model and the null problem is fixed.